# What is the relationship between Apps Script Errors, Internet connectivity, and local memory?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, memory, connectivity, chromebook

I am experiencing many errors on a Chromebook while I am trying to run an Apps Script function, and I would like to get feedback about the relationship between running the *cloud* script, internet connectivity, and the local memory of the machine.

First I will describe the errors, and then I will present my questions:

The first time the script stopped working, I got a "**Warning Lost connection to the server. please try again later**" at the footer of the execution Log. I ran the script again, and I got the same error.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome browser that shows a Google Sheets Apps Script project's editor and execution log. Notification Warning lost connection to the server. please try again later. appears at the bottom of the window.]

So I ran a Diagnostics Connectivity test which showed "**WARNING: Internet Connectivity: High latency to HTTPS websites.**"

[image: Screenshot of Chromebook's Diagnostic that shows the Connectivity Test FAILED Internet Connectivity High latency to HTTP websites]

I tried to run the script again, and now I started to get the error "**Function execution has timed out. Restart the debugger and continue debugging.**"

[image: Screenshot of Chrome browser that shows a Google Sheets Apps Script project's editor and execution log. Notification 'Function execution has timed out. Restart the debugger to continue debugging.' appears at the top of the Execution log section.]

In Chromebook, I ran a Diagnostics Connectivity Test again, and I get this other error "**FAILED Name Resolution DNS resolution has high latency.**"

[image: Screenshot of Chromebook's Diagnostic that shows the 'Connectivity Test FAILED Name Resolution DNS resolution has high latency]

I check the Chrome browser task a manager, and I see the tab from which I am running the script with the following memory stats:

- Memory footprint: 2,388,248K
- Swapped memory 1,700,700K
- JavaScript memory 139,880K(131,468K live)

[image: Screenshot of Chrome's Task Manager shows the tab from which the Google Sheets Apps Script project is running is using over 2GB of Memory footprint, over 1.5GB of Swap memory, and 140MG of JavaScript memory]

**So I am wondering**:

- The Script Apps I am running are not causing the connectivity problems. Am I wrong?
- Is the script supposed to consume memory from my machine or the cloud?
- This is a Google Sheets script, and [from some earlier reading of another Q&A, I understand I cannot generate output to console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377640/printing-to-the-console-in-google-apps-script#answer-12379623) b/c it all runs in the cloud. Is this assumption wrong? if this assumption is right, why is the Script consuming so much local memory?

Comment: I would guess that you have a lousy internet connection.  If you have a VPN that uses a cache you might wish to turn if off during debugging.  You might also like to just empty browsing data.  If it was your code you would probably have receive a specific code error.  Try turn of your computer and start it again.

Comment: What is considered a lousy internet connection? I am not aware of using a VPN; at least I did not set one up for the Chromebook. The Cox Cable internet service is supposed to be 50x10MBPS. I connect only through Ethernet. What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

I greatly suspect that Google offloads the processing to your computer when it can. I had execution differences between different browsers but didn't find any info on that.
You could simply try to create a trigger that run you function and let it run to be sure your computer is not used and watch the processing time.
Another thing is that when you manually run a script, if your computer disconnects from the web the execution if often failed or cancelled.
What's your latency against google's dns (8.8.8.8 for example) ?