Console.Log in Apps Script returns correct order but Google Sheets does not
I am creating a sheet for a gaming organization I am a part of. I am attempting to sort a list of names based on characteristics of their in-game character. After checking the output of a particular sort function through Console.log() I see the correct order. However, when I use the same formula inside of Google Sheets, the custom order is ignored and I receive the order as if the sort never happened.
The entirety of my code is as follows:
const BOSSES = ['Magmaw','Omnotron Defense System','Chimaeron','Atramedes','Maloriak','Nefarian','Halfus Wyrmbreaker','Valiona and Theralion','Ascendant Council','Cho\'gall','Sinestra','Conclave of Wind','Al\'Akir'];
const CLASSES = ['Death Knight', 'Druid', 'Hunter', 'Mage', 'Paladin', 'Priest', 'Rogue', 'Shaman', 'Warlock', 'Warrior'];
const ROLES = ['Tank','Healer','Melee','Ranged'];
const SPECID = {
    250: { class: "Death Knight", spec: "Blood", role: "Tank" },
    251: { class: "Death Knight", spec: "Frost", role: "Melee" },
    252: { class: "Death Knight", spec: "Unholy", role: "Melee" },
    102: { class: "Druid", spec: "Balance", role: "Ranged" },
    103: { class: "Druid", spec: "Feral", role: "Melee" },
    104: { class: "Druid", spec: "Guardian", role: "Tank" },
    105: { class: "Druid", spec: "Restoration", role: "Healer" },
    253: { class: "Hunter", spec: "Beast Mastery", role: "Ranged" },
    254: { class: "Hunter", spec: "Marksmanship", role: "Ranged" },
    255: { class: "Hunter", spec: "Survival", role: "Ranged" },
    62 : { class: "Mage", spec: "Arcane", role: "Ranged" },
    63 : { class: "Mage", spec: "Fire", role: "Ranged" },
    64 : { class: "Mage", spec: "Frost", role: "Ranged" },
    65 : { class: "Paladin", spec: "Holy", role: "Healer" },
    66 : { class: "Paladin", spec: "Protection", role: "Tank" },
    70 : { class: "Paladin", spec: "Retribution", role: "Melee" },
    256: { class: "Priest", spec: "Discipline", role: "Healer" },
    257: { class: "Priest", spec: "Holy", role: "Healer" },
    258: { class: "Priest", spec: "Shadow", role: "Ranged" },
    259: { class: "Rogue", spec: "Assassination", role: "Melee" },
    260: { class: "Rogue", spec: "Combat", role: "Melee" },
    261: { class: "Rogue", spec: "Subtlety", role: "Melee" },
    262: { class: "Shaman", spec: "Elemental", role: "Ranged" },
    263: { class: "Shaman", spec: "Enhancement", role: "Melee" },
    264: { class: "Shaman", spec: "Restoration", role: "Healer" },
    265: { class: "Warlock", spec: "Affliction", role: "Ranged" },
    266: { class: "Warlock", spec: "Demonology", role: "Ranged" },
    267: { class: "Warlock", spec: "Destruction", role: "Ranged" },
    71 : { class: "Warrior", spec: "Arms", role: "Melee" },
    72 : { class: "Warrior", spec: "Fury", role: "Melee" },
    73 : { class: "Warrior", spec: "Protection", role: "Tank" },
};

const SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const SHEET_ROSTER = SHEET.getSheetByName('ROSTER');
const SHEET_COMP = SHEET.getSheetByName('COMP');
const RANGE_ROSTER = SHEET_ROSTER.getRange(2, 1, SHEET_ROSTER.getLastRow() - 1, SHEET_ROSTER.getLastColumn()).getValues();
const RANGE_COMP = SHEET_COMP.getRange(1, 1, SHEET_COMP.getLastRow(), SHEET_COMP.getLastColumn()).getValues();

const ROSTER = RANGE_ROSTER.map(([nick, char, specid, parse]) => ({ nick, char, specid, parse }));
const COMPS = RANGE_COMP[0].map((_, colIndex) => RANGE_COMP.map(row => row[colIndex]));

function test() {
    console.log(setSortedNicks(getRolesFromComp(0,"Melee")));
}

function getDataBySpecID(specid, key) {
    const data = SPECID[specid];
    return data ? data[key] : 'Unknown';
}

function getData(nick, key) {
    const data = ROSTER.find(row => row.nick === nick);
    return data ? data[key] || getDataBySpecID(data.specid, key) : 'Unknown';
}

function setSortedNicks(comp, customOrder = ROLES) {
  const roleIndices = new Map();
  const dataMap = new Map();

  // Pre-compute role indices and dataMap for faster sorting
  for (const nick of comp) {
    const role = getData(nick, 'role');
    const roleIndex = customOrder.indexOf(role);
    const class_ = getData(nick, 'class');
    dataMap.set(nick, { roleIndex, class_ });
    roleIndices.set(nick, roleIndex);
  }

  comp.sort((a, b) => {
    const aData = dataMap.get(a);
    const bData = dataMap.get(b);

    // Sort by role indices
    const roleDiff = aData.roleIndex - bData.roleIndex;
    if (roleDiff !== 0) return roleDiff;

    // If roles are the same, sort by class
    return aData.class_.localeCompare(bData.class_);
  });

  return comp;
}

function getRolesFromComp(boss, role, ...roles) {
    return COMPS[boss].filter(nick => role === getData(nick, 'role') || roles.includes(getData(nick, 'role')));
}

function getSpecsFromComp(boss, spec, ...specs) {
    return COMPS[boss].filter(nick => spec === getData(nick, 'spec') || specs.includes(getData(nick, 'spec')));
}

Data for the comps is located on two different sheets as referenced in the header of the code. Everything seems to function just fine except for the setSortedNicks() inside of Google Sheets itself. I've been searching for some time for a solution and I'm unable to find one. The best thing I've come across is Sheets formulas doesn't do well with objects and prefers arrays. Any attempt to get the correct type has ultimately failed for me. I'm at a loss and any help would be appreciated.

You're working with Google Sheets and console.log works? It shouldn't. Google sheet works with Logger.log. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377640/printing-to-the-console-in-google-apps-script
